# Obtaining an instance of CommPortIdentifier on Android

Tags: java, android, modbus, securitymanager

I'm using Jamod 1.2 to establish Modbus TCP connection between an Android device and PLC. Everything was fine until I was asked to migrate to Modbus RTU (connecting via USB). Jamod has classes to work with Modbus RTU but I've encountered a specific problem.
To establish Modbus RTU connection one have to do these simple manipulations:

```
SerialParameters params = new SerialParameters();
params.setPortName(portname);
...
SerialConnection connection = new SerialConnection(params);
connection.open();
```

But the connection doesn't open due to the following obstacle:

```
public class SerialConnection implements SerialPortEventListener {
    ...
    public void open() throws Exception {
            try {
                this.m_PortIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(this.m_Parameters.getPortName());
            } catch (NoSuchPortException var2) {
                if(Modbus.debug) {
                    System.out.println(var2.getMessage());
                }

                throw new Exception(var2.getMessage());
            }
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Here the lib is trying to get an instance of CommPortIdentifier with a static method CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(String portname). Going deeper:

```
public class CommPortIdentifier {
    public static CommPortIdentifier getPortIdentifier(String var0) throws NoSuchPortException {
        SecurityManager var1 = System.getSecurityManager();
        if(var1 != null) {
            var1.checkDelete(propfilename);
        }
    ...
    }
...
}
```

And here is the root of the evil - System.getSecurityManager(). It always returns null in Android. [official doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html#getSecurityManager())

Finally, **the question**: is there a way to generate CommPortIdentifier on Android? Or may be someone can think of another solution to the problem?

**P.S.** I would like to avoid replacing Jamod with something else or writing my own Modbus RTU wrapper because a lot of code depend on the lib. Unless there is no other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up writing my own Modbus RTU wrapper for Android. Its basic implementation can be found here: https://github.com/dh-28/ModbusRtuConnect